# Compare two class attributes using a JPA method

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to compare two attributes using JPA method convention.

This is my class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aircrafts")
public class Aircrafts {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "number", length = 45)
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private int capacity;

    @Column(name = "seats_taken")
    private int seatsTaken;
}
```

And this the method I want to implement :

```
public interface AircraftsRepository extends JpaRepository<Aircrafts, Long> {
    public List<Aircrafts> findBySeatsTakenLessThanCapacity();
}
```

However I got this exception:

```
PropertyReferenceException: No property lessThanCapacity found for type int! Traversed path: Aircrafts.seatsTaken.
```

I've tried using int and Integer but I got the same exception. Which is the correct method name?

Comment: `@Query("select a from Aircrafts a where a.seatsTaken < a.capacity")`. Bonus point: you can now choose a decent, readable name for your method.

Comment: Thanks, I know that solution. I want to find a way using method name convention. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know. I wouldn't search for a complex solution that is worse than the obvious, trivial one that doesn't need searching.

Comment: Use this method. No need to write any query.
public List<Aircrafts> findBySeatsTakenLessThanCapacity(int capacity);

Comment: Thanks @Prasath I need to compare SeatsTaken and Capacity with the values of the DB.

Comment: You are trying to squeeze 2 entities into one: aircraft and flight. A flight has a certain route, time, aircraft. You can then test with flight.getSeatsTaken()<aircraft.getCapacity().

Comment: It's the same table. The Aircraft table has both fields SeatsTaken and Capacity

Answer (score 0):

I think @benji2505, correctly mentioned that the data model mixes things that "should" be in different tables. Normally one would expect two tables: Aircrafts, Flights.

Then you could easily use:

```
List<Flight> flightsWithFreeSeats = aircraftRepository
.findAll()
.stream()
.map(aircraft ->
 flightRepository.findByAircraftAndSeatsTakenLessThen(aircraft, aircraft.getCapacity)
)
.collect(Collectors.toList)
```

With current model probably @JZ Nizet already posted the best answer in his comment.